# Jsonp + javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

Im using chrome with the last version.

Im building a chrome extension and in one site inject a javascript file, in this file a want get a json from other server..

This is the url that contain the json:

http://api.trakt.tv/show/episode/summary.json/368b0395732268808fa8d151d2484e8c/Firefly/1/5

and this is the code on my js

```
var url = 'http://api.trakt.tv/show/episode/summary.json/368b0395732268808fa8d151d2484e8c/Firefly/1/5?callback=?';
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    async: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {
       console.dir(json);
    },
    error: function(e) {
       console.log(e.message);
    }
});
```

Always run the error and i get the message 'undefined'

Comment: change url to : `http://api.trakt.tv/show/episode/summary.json/368b0395732268808fa8d151d2484e8c/Firefly/1/5` the callback is messing the response up with a `?`

Comment: no prob we all make little mistakes!